# I use a fake REST API, with a database. Want to go live and have a db interface

Tags: javascript, database, json-server

So basically i'm using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), which gives a full fake REST API. It creates a local database in JSON format, that i have customized. From it, i fetch data, and generate simple HTML for the sake of simplicity.
What i want to do next, is have the app and database live, and an interface for the database where i can interact with it in the browser.
What services/technologies are there that can help me do this?

Any road opening or advice are much appreciated!

Code i think is not relevant here.

Comment: This will probs get closed. Whilst that's happening, check out MongoDB

Comment: Depending on your needs, check out SQLite.  It has a nice JSON extension, and is quite efficient!

Comment: You can check out [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) (I'm the author). It behaves like json-server, but with a database backend.